# cannot run BeautifulSoup using requests.get(url)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
start_url=requests.get('http://www.delicious.com/golisoda')
soup=BeautifulSoup(start_url)
```

this code is displaying the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2_requests.py", line 10, in <module>
    soup=BeautifulSoup(start_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.builder.prepare_markup(markup, from_encoding))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 68, in prepare_markup
    dammit = UnicodeDammit(markup, try_encodings, is_html=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 203, in __init__
    self._detectEncoding(markup, is_html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 373, in _detectEncoding
    xml_encoding_match = xml_encoding_re.match(xml_data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `.content` of the response:

```
start_url = requests.get('http://www.delicious.com/golisoda')
soup = BeautifulSoup(start_url.content)
```

Alternatively, you can use the decoded unicode text:

```
start_url = requests.get('http://www.delicious.com/golisoda')
soup = BeautifulSoup(start_url.text)
```

See the [Response content section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Martijn,
the code is running now.. but still I'm unable to save the result into a text file.

`fw.write(string)`

Comment: @YogeshKumar: could you elaborate? What result do you want to safe in a text file?

Comment: I want the title and the link to it to be saved in a file. With urllib2 without encoding I was able to save it in a .txt file, but when i used encoding with urllib2 and used requests I was not able to save them into the file.

Answer (score 0):

you probebly need to Use

using

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(start_url.read())
```

or

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(start_url.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
data=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.delicious.com/golisoda').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
```

Comment: **I was using urllib2 earlier but while fetching data from a site it displayed** `UnicodeEncodingError`

**so the i switched to requests and I'm still not able to save data on a .txt file...**